# Google Sheets referencing values from another sheet using dynamic value calculated in current sheet

Tags: excel, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

In Google Sheets I need to reference a cell by (column, row) in another sheet.

I am using the following formula right now:

```
=countif('Oct 2019'!H:H, "=✅")
```

Here **Oct 2019** is the a different sheet in the same worksheet.

However, the string **Oct 2019** is present in many formulas and in next row which is for **Nov 2019** I have to manually make the changes.

Is there a way where I can replace **Oct 2019** by a variable and that variable can reference to a value n the original sheet ?

I have tried

```
=countif("INDIRECT(A8)"&!H:H, "=✅")
```

where cell ***A8*** in current sheet has the value **Oct 2019** but it gives me formula parse error.

Can someone help with this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Indirect()` like below.

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'" & A8 & "'!H:H"),"=✅")
```

Comment: this was the perfect answer. I have a follow up question related to the same. 
=INDIRECT("'" & A11 & "'!A100")

In the above formula is it possible to read the value 100 dynamically to finally make it A100 ?

Comment: @CodeMonkey If you found the answer helpful then consider it as accepted (Tick as green). Yes, that is possible. Please explain more...

Comment: So the formula looks like this :
=INDIRECT("'" & A11 & "'!A100")

I want to get that value of 100 from another cell and populate it in subsequent variable. 

For e.g. cell M10 = 100

My formulas can be :
 =INDIRECT("'" & A11 & "'!A(VALUEOF(M10)") which translates to =INDIRECT("'" & A11 & "'!A100")
    =INDIRECT("'" & A11 & "'!A(VALUEOF(M10) + 1")  which translates to =INDIRECT("'" & A11 & "'!A101")

Comment: @CodeMonkey Then try this `=SUM(INDIRECT(A11 & ":A" & M10))`.